# Why is '#' symbol used in C language's header ? Why not any other symbol ?

Tags: c++, c, header

I want to know why is that a C language's header contains '#' symbol as the starting symbol and why not any other symbol was used for that purpose ? Is there any reason for that or else the programmers just selected it randomly ?

Comment: It is not some "random programmers" who designed C. And such choices are somehow arbitrary. Even if we use + to denote addition, aliens' math books are very likely to use some other symbol for the same addition.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Was my guess right when I said it might be because the rest of the characters were used up as operators? I know not all but still....

Comment: If it were some other symbol (say, `$`), wouldn't you be asking the same question?

Comment: I always answer such a questions - why not? If another character would be picked, you will ask - why that one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because poster should demonstrate some understanding

Comment: It didn't get them from B or BCPL, which used a different syntax.  Ritchie writes that the preprocessor was introduced "around 1972-3".

Comment: And it's neither from the PL/I preprocessor (which Ritchie also mentions as a source of `#include` and `#define` directives), which uses `%INCLUDE` according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I_preprocessor). (Looks awesome, btw, a preprocessor with `%GOTO`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would guess that the requirements were

- available in the common character sets of the time (ASCII, EBCDIC, and perhaps others)
- not otherwise used by the language, so the preprocessor could easily identify its directives
- easy to type on a standard US keyboard

There aren't many characters that meet these requirements; `#` is one. The choice of that, rather than `@` or `$` for example, was probably arbitrary.

Comment: Also, at that time it was ASCII (at the best). Unicode did not exist then

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Good point. Even today, the source character set is a subset of ASCII.

Answer (score 7):

The primary reason is that the `#` is unused elsewhere in the C syntax. This allows it to be used for the (then separate) preprocessor.

Comment: I also discussed this question with my professor, and he told that '#' symbol was used in assembly language for immediate addressing and based on that , Dennies Ritchie used '#' to include the header files in an immediate manner. I am not sure whether this answer is also correct or not.